# Django 1.4 without the csrf_token

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I've just upgraded Django from 1.2.3 to 1.4 and realized that django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware is depricated. Is there some other way where I don't have to use the csrf_token in every post? It will be easier for the front end designers to not have to worry about django specific tokens.

Comment: "It will be easier for front-end designers to ensure that my system is open to attack and compromise the security of my users."

Comment: It would be, but the application that I'm building is only for internal use and every user is already authenticated using shibboleth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#utilities), especially [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) and [`csrf_protect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect) decorators.

You could then use `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` for default csrf protecting w/ `csrf_exempt` to exempt special views; or only use `csrf_protect` for each view to protect.

Comment: Thanks, since it is for an internal tool the security is not an issue and the csrf_exempt works fine, but I was hoping for something more automatic. It would be awesome if something could be added in the form class.

Answer (score 0):

According to the release notes there is now a `ensure_csrf_cookie`-decorator:
[decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) and [csrf-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Comment: I don't think that the ensure_csrf_cookie decorator does what I want. The documentation is pretty bad with the official documentation just says 'read the release notes' and the release notes just links you to the documentation :)

Comment: Seems like the documentation in this case, is a nice example of how circular references don't help anyone :)